# What are these components in block diagram of STM32?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, stm32, dac

Today, when I was seeing in [STM32F103RET6 datasheet](http://www.espruino.com/datasheets/STM32F103xC.pdf) I saw some odd things(also, they are odd for me, probably you have enough information about these). if look in 12P of datasheet, you will see this picture:

[image: Performance line block diagram]

I have determined 3 point of it and have several question about these three point:

- for number one: What is this part and What does it do? (I mean "Obl")
- for number two: How does this power switch work?(I mixed up, Does it work automatically?)
- for number three: What's the mean of the "IF" word? If you consider, even, you will see the "IF" for ADC units(not just for DAC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OBL = Option Byte Loader. Found it in [this](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/CD00264852.pdf) datasheet. At page 19 is a short description of what it does.

Probably that switch is automatically triggered in standby/battery mode.

In Radiofrequency applications, IF usually means Intermediate Frequency. But in this case:

IF = Interface as [PeterJ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/17064/peterj) suggested in the first comment.

Comment: Agree with 1 & 2 and was about to post a similiar answer, but I thought IF being interface might make more sense in that context when it applies to the ADC as well? Not 100% sure though.

Comment: I thought about the sampling frequency when I said Intermediate Frequency. I'm not sure either.

Comment: For 2, then when the MCU is in other mode(except active mode), it will use battery, is it correct?

Comment: @Roh it will use battery power for running a 32kHz oscillator needed by RTC and to preserve registers.

Comment: @Cornelius For everytime? I mean, it won't use battery power in normal mode of MCU. is it correct?

Comment: @Roh I guess it's not open circuit. It will still draw a tiny amount of current, microAmps. I can't find that info in the datasheet but check Table 17 / page 48